# Electrocatalysis of Hydrogen Evolution Reaction with metal oxides

Tags: reaction-mechanism, electrochemistry, hydrogen, catalysis

I'm new to the topic of electrocatalysis so I have a few questions. Also, I don't have much knowledge about thermodynamics, but I will try to ask anyway.

I'm looking for a material to catalyze the Hydrogen Evolution Reaction for $\ce{H2}$ production. So, for pure metals we have the Volcano curve:
 [image: volcano curve]

Then, with this curve, I found in literature that we can mix metals from the different branches (positive and negative slopes) and get a new alloy with an intermediate M-H energy strength (which is desirable to improve the catalyst activity.)

But, I want to know if there exists the same curve (and the same logic) for metal oxides, because I need to predict if an alloy of rhenium oxides with copper oxides are going to be a better catalyst than only rhenium oxides.

Is there some method of theory to predict this before going to the lab and doing some experiments?

Comment: Presence of Titanium on this diagram is hilarious. It's good there is no aluminium here, or I'd laughed my ass off.

Comment: 1) Is there “oxide alloys”? I am not sure the two oxides can freely mix. 2) There can similar volcano curves depending on the mechanism of reaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a similar, DFT-based approach to estimating the electrocatalytic activity of oxides, as has been done with the [oxygen evolution reaction](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cctc.201000397/abstract), but since most oxides are not stable at reducing conditions present in HER, there's not as much literature on that particular material-reaction pairing.  As an aside, a popular theory of metal-adsorbate bond formation, the [d-band model](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/3/937.full) was formulated specifically for metals, so the question as to whether or not there's a model with comparable simplicity that includes oxides (or other binary compounds) is still somewhat of an open question.